# Handling long file uploads with Django on GKE

Tags: django, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I need to be able to upload large files on a Django app hosted on GKE which can take a long time if the connection is slow. I'm relying on `gunicorn` to serve the application. The problem I have is: once I start the file upload, the gunicorn worker is stuck processing the upload request and cannot process anything else. As a result, kubernetes cannot access the liveness probe and restart the container, which kills the upload. It also means my site is very unresponsive.

I could add more gunicorn worker but it's not a proper solution since users can upload many files in parallel. It would just increase the threshold of what I can manage.

Scaling up would solve the responsiveness but not the fact the user needs time to upload the file.

Since this issue is usually (by usually I mean when not running on kubernetes) solved by putting a nginx sever in front of `gunicorn`, I was wandering how I could to this with kubernetes. I think I have two solutions:

- Add an nginx sidecar in the pod. This looks simple enough and would avoids installing something cluster wide. I can also let the GKE ingress handle HTTPS traffic.
- Switch ingress to use a nginx based one instead of the default GKE one. From what I saw [here](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke), this is possible. This could solve the issue for all services and would avoid wasting resources on each pod.

Do you have any feedback on this (or other solutions)? I'm still new to kubernetes and don't really understand all the implications of doing this.

Comment: you can use any ingress GKE or Nginx ingress.

Comment: I know. The problem I have is that the default GKE one doesn't buffer requests, which means my `gunicorn` workers can get stuck (as I describe in my answer). I don't know whether by switching to the nginx ingress one, it would work better (like I was using a standard nginx reverse proxy).

Comment: that's better you can give it try if it's working with nginx RP thn will work with nginx ingress also.

Comment: If you are interested, here's a guide on how to deploy this with nginx ingress https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke